# Thread safety warnings

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency, apache-commons-math

I'm using `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution` in a large distributed Scala & Akka application.  During debugging I found `sample()` was occasionally returning NaN, which propagated silently and caused threads to hang in `org.apache.commons.math3.ode.nonstiff.DormandPrince853Integrator`

The NaN can be reproduced simply with parallel colelctions (doesn't happen in sequential code):

```
val normal = new NormalDistribution(0,0.1)
(1 to 1000000000).par.foreach{i =>
    val r = normal.sample
    if(r.isNaN()) throw new Exception("r = "+r)
}
```

Obviously moving the `val normal` inside the `foreach` solves the issue in this case.

I've looked at the [docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/NormalDistribution.html) but can't see anything warning me of such issues.  Have I failed to grasp a more fundamental concept about thread safety?  Needless to say I'm now checking for NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [digging through sources](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/NormalDistribution.java?view=markup) you can find that this constructor uses [`Well19937c`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/random/Well19937c.java?view=markup) random generator, which doesn't look thread-safe by itself at the first glance.

You can make it thread safe, by explicitly setting the number generator to [`SynchronizedRandomGenerator`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/random/SynchronizedRandomGenerator.java?view=markup) which wraps any other random number generator (like `Well19937c` or `Mersenne Twister`). Note that by synchronizing access to random number generator with `SynchronizedRandomGenerator` you'll lose all potential performance benefits and the 'parallel' version will be probably slower than a sequential one because of the synchronization. On the other hand, re-initializing the random distribution on every iteration in parallel will probably re-seed the PRNG multiple times with similar values based on current time, so your results will be skewed.

A very general rule of the thumb (and if I'm wrong here, please correct me) is that 99% of the time, unless explicitly stated otherwise, you should probably stick to sequential execution when doing anything that relies on random number generation, as usually PRNGs will store state that might get corrupted when calling them from multiple threads. And unless you're doing expensive computations afterwards, the synchronization (in case of thread-safe stateful PRNGs) will be a bottleneck.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt True, and good catch! Someone who knows apache.commons.math might guide the person asking the question how to plumb it into the random distributions, if it's even possible. I really don't know a thing about that library, so I can't help there...

Answer (score 2):

A middle ground would be to create `normal` as a thread local, perhap's by using Twitter's [`Local` implementation](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Local.scala).

This would help if the `normal.sample` method was particularly expensive.  You can also be certain that no two parallel operations will be running on the same thread at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

It appens probably because you're using a non-threadsafe object in multithreaded environment (you are calling method sample twice or more concurrently).
You have to use another thread-safe generator or an instance of NormalDistribution for each thread or synchronize access to single instance (probably losing any benefit of par execution).

Answer (score 1):

Try using another thread-safe generator or an instance of NormalDistribution for each thread or synchronize access to single instance. Because I think that you are using  a non-threadsafe object in multi threaded environment